# Amazon S3 Bucket policy to allow user to write to the bucket but that bucket only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in Amazon S3 called 'data1'.

When I connect using Cyberduck to my S3, I want the user to only have access to 'data1' bucket and none of the others.

I also set up a new IAM user, called data1, and attached the 'AmazonS3FullAccess' policy to the permissions for that user - but that gives access to all of the buckets - which is what you would expect.

I guess I need to setup another policy for this - however what policy would I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic AWS IAM permissions for an S3 bucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073755/basic-aws-iam-permissions-for-an-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First find the users principle.  These can be found by looking at the Arn field output by this command

```
aws iam list-users
```

For instance

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "UserName": "eric",
            "Path": "/",
            "CreateDate": "2016-07-12T09:08:21Z",
            "UserId": "AIDAJXPI4SWK7X7PY4RX2",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::930517348925:user/eric"
        },
        {
            "UserName": "bambi",
            "Path": "/",
            "CreateDate": "2015-07-15T11:07:16Z",
            "UserId": "AIDAJ2LEXFRXJI5AKUU7W",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::930517348725:user/bambi"
        }
]
}
```

Then set up an S3 bucket policy.  These apply to the bucket and are set per bucket.  Normal IAM policies are set per IAM entity and are attached to the IAM entity, for instance the user.  You already have IAM policies.  For this requirement an S3 policy is needed.

Just to emphasise - S3 policies apply to the bucket and are "attached" to S3, IAM policies apply to IAM and are associated with IAM objects.  When IAM entities try to use an S3 bucket both S3 policys and IAM policies can apply.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Once you know the ARN of the principle then add a S3 policy like this

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::930517348725:user/bambi",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid":"block",
      "Effect":"Deny",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::930517348725:user/bambi",
      "Action":["s3:*"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven't tested this but that is the general idea.  Sorry I didn't use "data1" for both the principle and bucket name in the example but it's too confusing..:)

Answer (score 1):

For write-only access you can attach a policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but it reads like you want to do more than just write?